# In angular7, how to get combined response from 2 different dependent http call. first http call returns an array of object and other its related data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

My first api returns following data

```
{
"resp": [
  {
    "id": "932e",
    "name": "jon"        
  },
  {
    "id": ...
    "name": ..,
  }
]
```

}

I have to loop through this array and make another call to API using above id,  which returns data like this

```
{
"posts": [
  {
    "id": "1111",
    "title": "post on facebook"        
  },
  {
    "id": "2222",
    "title": "post on covid"        
  }

]
```

Final
data should be in this format

```
{
  "resp": [
    {
      "id": "932e",
      "name": "jon",
      "posts": [
        {
          "id": "1111",
          "name": "post on facebook"
        },
        {
          "id": "2222",
          "name": "post on covid"
        }
      ]
    }   
  ]
}
```

signature of method which makes call to 2nd api like this

```
public getUsersPost(userId) {

     return this.datasetService.getPosts(userId).pipe(
      map(ds => {
        return ds.posts
      }));
  }
```

Not sure how to use map, mergreMap or concatMap for >

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of mapping operator depends on the loading strategy you want. `mergeMap` sends all the requests in parallel (you can limit the maximum number of simultaneous requests), whereas `concatMap` will execute them in series. I'd also recommend splitting the first Array into its component parts.

I suspect you want something along these lines:

```js
const populatedUsers$ = this.getUsers.pipe(
  mergeMap(userArray => from(userArray)), // now emitting each user separately)
  mergeMap(user => this.getUsersPost(user.id).pipe(
    map(ds => ({ ...user, posts: ds.posts }))
  ), null, 5), // maximum of 5 concurrent requests
  toArray() // convert everything back to a single array
);
```

Comment: Thank Will. Your answer is precise.

Comment: You're very welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer so that your question appears as answered and others can find it more easily?